# Why my ASP.NET application broke after a migration?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, migration, windows-server-2008

My web application worked very well in a Windows Server 2003 with .NET Framework 2.0. When I migrated to Windows Server 2008 with .NET Framework 3.5.

With the same code running in both servers the difference between them was the following: for a given async ASHX (IHttpAsyncHandler) the previous server automatically answered the request with the Connection and Content-Length headers. As the new server didn't automatically generated those headers with the previous code, I had to alter the code to do it manually, or otherwise the web clients couldn't determine the end of the response.

My question is, isn't .NET Framework 3.5 supposed to maintain full backwards compatibility with .NET 2.0?

Comment: I see that you might have multiple servers with different evironments on them - IMO this can quickly turn into a web.config hell. If you have this problem, consider having multiple web.configs - one for each server - say, web.dev.config and web.test.config and web.live.config, and the web.config . Whenever you switch your app to a new server, take all of the configs with you, and just copy the contents of the corresponding web.?.config file into the web.config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the ApplicationPool mode to Classic.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the .Net Framework it's the different between IIS7 and IIS6. As [leppie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15541/leppie) stated you need to set the application pool to classic mode.